# js open popup window and acces its element in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a problem with js popup window.

I open a popup and try to access its elements in another page page, no success, and I don't want to reload the popup source, I simply want access a element of the opened popup

Ex -

- 1st page - opened popup with html5 music player
- 2nd page - need to pause the music when user click on button on main page

1st page

```
var popup = window.open("test.html","mypopup","width=500,height=300");
```

2nd page I want to access mypopup windows elements without reloading the popup

I only need the way how to access opened popup elements without interrupting its sources using JS or JQuery

Comment: Same origin (domain, port and protocol)? Plain JS: `popup.document.getElementById("player").someFunction()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Same origin (domain, port and protocol)?

Plain JS:

from page1

```
var popup = window.open("test.html","mypopup","width=500,height=300");
popup.document.getElementById("player").someFunction();
```

from page 2

```
var popup = window.open('','mypopup');
// now popup is known again
popup.document.getElementById("player").someFunction();
```

Comment: What happend if i dont have access to the code that invokes `popup`? but still want to access the DOM from another page?

Comment: Please ask your own question... If the code that invokes it gave the popup a name or used a handle you can use it like I show in page 2- if it just does a `window.open("url.html")` then not. If you have scripting access to the page, you can rewrite the function that pops the page. `function popup() { /* myVersion of this */}` will overwrite `function popup() { /* their version */}` if you load yours after theirs and keep the name