# Rotate image in browse popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with image thumbnails that I enclosed in anchor tags, such that when clicked, a bigger image will be shown in a separate browser popup window.

JSP:

```
<a href="#"><img id="<c:out value='${theImg.imgID}'/>" src="<c:out     value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>/ImageServlet?imgID=<c:out value='${theImg.imgID}'/>" width="50" height="50" onClick='showImage("<c:out value='${pageContext.request.contextPath}'/>/ImageServlet?imgID=<c:out value='${theImg.imgID}'/>","<c:out value='${theImg.imgID}'/>");' border="0" alt=""/></a>
```

Javascript:

```
win = window.open(url, "", "width=500, height=350, toolbar=yes, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no, location=no, top=285, left=575");
```

Now I want to add a rotate functionality to the image in the popup window (by default, browsers only provide zoom functionality). I know I can use something like JQueryRotate to add this functionality to an IMG element.  But the problem is I do not know how to get a handle or ID of the IMG element shown in the popup.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get a handle to the IMG element because the window that you opened shows only the image that you passed to it as a URL, it contains no HTML markup.

A better option might be to open an HTML page and then manipulate it's DOM. Here's a link that does something similar: [js open popup window and acces it's element in another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468136/js-open-popup-window-and-acces-its-element-in-another-page)

Comment: The key was definitely creating a separate JSP for the pop-up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the script directly to the popup window. Alternatively you could use jquery to make a pseudo popup that looks and feels a lot better.