# Open new tab then listen for an event being fired

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in Javascript to open up a new tab, and then listen for that tab firing an event?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038643/event-for-when-user-switches-browser-tabs) for listening to certain tab events, but can instead of `window`, I target the specific tab I opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work nicely for me

**In the parent window**

```
var form = window.open('/formsv2/add', '_blank', 'resizable=1', true);
form.addEventListener('formAdded', function(data) {
    console.log('formAddedEvent');
    console.log(data.name);
    console.log(data.id);
    $('#formIdSelect').append('<option value="'+data.id+'">'+data.name+'</option>').val(data.id);
});
```

**In the popup window**

```
var evt = document.createEvent("Events")
evt.initEvent('formAdded', true, true); //true for can bubble, true for cancelable
evt.name = $('#title').val();
evt.id = data.form;
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Comment: not every browser opens a new window in a new tab. You should point this out

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Well, not directly.

For obvious security reasons javascript can only access data from it's own tab/window. You can however use cookies, locastorage or ... to store and read data from the same domain.

You could add an EventListner to the localstorage object (that is shared between domains). Soundcloud for instance does this.

**Edit:** I think there is a confusion between window.open and a new tab.

window.open opens a pop up. You can then access that popup from within [your script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468136/js-open-popup-window-and-acces-its-element-in-another-page). Note however that behaviour of how pop-ups are shown vary from browser to browser. Some open it in a new tab, some in a new window, ... Note however that to be able to access the popup, it has to be same domain, protocol, port, ...

this however doesn't work if the user manually opens a new window/tab to your site because you don't have a reference to it.

Comment: Ahh okay, could this be done using `window.open` directly in Javascript? Or does the rule still apply then?

Comment: has nothing to do with it... Read my answer again ;) If both tabs/windows are on the same domain (e.g. soundcloud.com/a and soundcloud.com/b) it doens't matter how you open them. they will be aple to access the same localstorage object (and also cookies, ...)

Answer (score 1):

The following solution worked for me:

**Parent Window**

```
 var win = window;
 win.open('url', 'newWindow', 'height=300,width=300');

 win.addEventListener('message', function(response){
    console.log(response.data);
},false);
```

**Child Window**

```
window.opener.postMessage('Success', "*");
```